# How to enable the microphone on the android emulator from Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, microphone

I have an app running that is listening to - and will also record - audio on an ios9 emulated device. The microphone is not activated. How can that be done?

[image]

Oh here are the microphone settings on the emulator:

[image]

I also tried toggling each of the options but still no sound is being detected on the microphone.

Comment: See https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/emulator#29.0.6-host-audio

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I believe you should also switch on the host audio data. You could use the below ADB command to do so.

```
adb emu avd hostmicon
```

And to switch it off,

```
adb emu avd hostmicoff
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm able to get microphone host input and then play it on Android emulator using this answer.